# Fill in "gaps" in multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 28
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 1422.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 29
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 480.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 31
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 1472.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 32
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 910.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 33
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 740.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 34
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 380.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 35
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 640.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 36
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 340.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 37
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 1490.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 38
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 710.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 39
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 810.00
                        )

                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 40
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 3152.00
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How you can note, V starts from 28 (it's the num of week in selected year) and week 30 is missing.

Another query of database could, of course, return a different result, with others (or no) "gaps".

How I can "fill" that gaps? (If interesting, I know also the max numbers of weeks in a year, 52 or 53).

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I would an array as result as the following, with the "30" inserted in the array and the value at "0.00" (see following):

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [c] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => 28
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => 1422.00
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [c] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => 29
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => 480.00
                            )

                    )

            )

           [2] => Array
            (
                [c] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => 30
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [v] => 0.00
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? a list of numbers that are missing? (30 in this example)

Comment: OK, you are right. I need a final array with gaps "filled". Not a list but a single array "complete" (and the V value to the 0.00, cause are not present values for that week). Thank you!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the elements in "foreach-order" have strictly ascending values for `[0]v`? And would it be ok to use `[0]v` as the key for the outer array instead of 0,1,2,3...?

Comment: I'll post a solution after my coffee. ;-) Just a sec.

Comment: @VolkerK yes it's guaranteed, but I need to mantain the structure (it's a table for Google Chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that assumes the right input array format.

```
$org = array(
 ["c"=>[["v"=>28],["v"=>1422.00]]],
 ["c"=>[["v"=>29],["v"=>480.00]]],
 ["c"=>[["v"=>31],["v"=>1234.00]]],
 ["c"=>[["v"=>35],["v"=>432.00]]]
 // etc
);

$fixed = fixMe($org);

// I am expecting an array structured as in your example, so I am too lazy to check for errors.
function fixMe($arr){
    $foundWeekNums = array();
    foreach ($arr as $ind => $arr_1){
        $foundWeekNums[$arr_1["c"][0]["v"]] = $arr_1["c"][1]["v"];
    }

  // $keys are found weeknums
    $keys = array_keys($foundWeekNums);

    $formWeekNum = min($keys);
    $toWeekNum = max($keys);

    $newArr = array();

    for ($week = $formWeekNum; $week <= $toWeekNum; $week++){
        if (in_array($week, $keys)){
            $val = $foundWeekNums[$week];
        } else {
            $val = 0;
        }
        $newArr[] = ["c" => [["v" => $week],["v" => $val]]];
    }
    return $newArr;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($org);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<hr><pre>";
print_r($fixed);
echo "</pre>";
```

PS: If you want to fill up to 52 or 53, simple put that number in this place:

```
$toWeekNum = max($keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

So many possible ways ... here are just two ...

The simple straight-forward

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>28), array('v'=>'1422.00'))),
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>29), array('v'=>'480.00'))),
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>31), array('v'=>'1472.00'))),
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>40), array('v'=>'3152.00')))
);

$result = array();
$previous = current($arr)['c'][0]['v'] - 1 ; // you have to split this up into two statements if php version < 5.6
foreach($arr as $w) {
    while(++$previous < $w['c'][0]['v'] ) {
        $result[] = array('c'=>array(array('v'=>$previous), array('v'=>'0.00')));
    }
    $result[] = $w;
}

var_export($result);
```

and the one a bit more fun....

```
<?php
// see http://docs.php.net/class.arrayaccess
class Foo implements ArrayAccess {
    protected $data;
    protected $index;
    protected $year;
    protected $maxWeek;

    public function __construct($year, $weekRecords) {
        $this->data = $weekRecords;
        foreach( $weekRecords as $k=>$e ) {
            $w = $e['c'][0]['v'];
            $this->index[$w] = $k;
        }
        $this->year = $year;
        $dt = new DateTime('31.12.'.$year);
        $this->maxWeek = intval($dt->format('W')); // assuming ISO-week
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return $offset > 0 && $offset < $this->maxWeek;
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->index[$offset]) ?
            $this->data[ $this->index[$offset] ]
            : array('c'=>array(array('v'=>$offset), array('v'=>'0.00')));
    }

    public function offsetSet ($offset, $value ) {
        trigger_error('offsetSet not implemented', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    public function offsetUnset ($offset ) {
        trigger_error('offsetSet not implemented', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

/* ************ */
$arr = array(
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>28), array('v'=>'1422.00'))),
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>29), array('v'=>'480.00'))),
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>31), array('v'=>'1472.00'))),
    array('c'=>array(array('v'=>40), array('v'=>'3152.00')))
);

$foo = new Foo(2015, $arr);
for($i=28; $i<45; $i++) {
    var_export( $foo[$i] );
}
```

though you probably would also want to implement [Traversable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php).